# Android app: read texts in foreign language with translations

Tags: android, language, translation

#### I'm looking for:

I'm searching for Android app that allows user to read texts in foreign language. The main feature I look for is ability to click on word / sentence and get translation for this in my main language. Translation have to be prepared and validated (not auto-translation by Google or similar software).

#### Why it would be useful:

I would like to learn foreing language (German). I think that reading (and watching) in new language is a great way to learn new words and sentences that are often used. But at the beginning there is problem that you don't know many words and you have to stop very often to check unknown words in some other source (dictionary/translator). It can be exhausting and limit your joy of reading. Using app that I'm looking for would allow you to check word or sentence in context without need of losing focus on text.

#### Features

I would appreciate following features (not required):

- support for English, German and maybe Polish (but other languages would be great),
- classic texts (maybe Doyle, Verne, Orwell, Geothe), I would prefer some more known novels than texts prepared for this app. It could be novels, short stories, tales.
- ability to see translation for word and sentence (e.g. longer press would show sentence translation, tap would show world translation).

If something like ths doesn't exist on Android, maybe some PC, Web or iOS version is available?

**Budget:** I'm looking for Google Play app (or similar source), not custom solution. I'll be interested in paying per resource (book / text) or subscription (preferably per resource). I suspect that prices should be accessible to consumer (similar to price of book in bookstore or subscription similar to other media services - like VODs).

Comment: Are you willing to pay for it? If so, how much?

Comment: I can buy it as app from Google Play, no problem. I would prefer paying per resource (like per book / novel / text), but I would consider subscription model if that would be only option. I'm not interested in paying someone to create this or to order some custom solution. I guess that this should be prices like for book in bookstore (or slightly more expensive, but no 10 times more expensive).

Comment: Ok, then we don't add the [tag:gratis] tag. It is bets to either do that or state a budget in the question. Sometimes we get answers recommending software which costs thousands :-)  I am watching this question and hope that you get an answer, as I would like this too (maybe an idea for a new business, if you don't get an answer?)

Comment: OK, sorry. I didn't spend to much time here to know that. Information added to question. I would consider creating app like this, but licensing fees and translations could be really expensive... If there were API with that feature (I doubt it) maybe it'll be worth a show. :)

Comment: Don't worry about not adding a budget, but do read [ask], because better questions get better answers :-) That means the more info we get, the better help we give - although this might be a tough one. Welcome aboard!